# Why dc.js doesnt draw choropleth map?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I tried to make map with dc.js library but it doesnt draw the map.

I used "US Venture Capital Landscape 2011" example.([link](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/))

Here my codes:

```
 trChart.width(800)
        .height(500) 
        .dimension(ilDim)
        .group(ilGroup)
        .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
        .colorDomain([0, 200])
        .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? trChart.colors()(d) : \'#ccc\'; }) 
        .overlayGeoJson(map.features, "SEHIR", function (d) {
        return d.properties.title; 
        })
        .title(function (d) {  
        return "Sehir: " + d.key + "\nICD Frekansı: " + (d.value ? d.value : 0) ; 
        });
```

Here my geojson map link:[map.json](http://kds.saglik.gov.tr/map.json)

Where am I wrong?

I used for map title properties:

```
  "properties": {
        "name": "ED",
        "title":"Edirne"
      },
```

Comment: Your links are broken, please fix. Also,  why are you using multiple identities?

Comment: Looks like you got your answers [on the dc.js user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/SaKFfLm511U/b8SAPqrZ3EoJ)

Comment: Not completly got answer.I didnt solve map projection

Comment: I answered that, projection is in the [public API](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#projectionprojection). You should really look there before asking, although many of your other questions are good ones!

Comment: Sorry Gordon.I saw your answer.But I used public API this:var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
    .scale(3000)
    .origin([27.03,42.37])
    .mode("equalarea")
    .translate([50, 100]);  But it doesnt helped me.

Comment: I don't know enough to help you there, and I'm not sure if anyone could help you without a fiddle, but you might also try [PR #719](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/719), which includes auto zoom to the current map.