# map json works on Geojson.io but it doesnt work on dc.js choropleth map

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I created geojson turkey map on [geojson.io](http://geojson.io). It works on geojson.io with no trouble.But it doesnt work on 
dc.js choropleth map.

I checked it with us-states.json on my codes it works but my geojson map doesnt work.

Here My created geojson:

[mygeojson](http://kds.saglik.gov.tr/map.json)

Comment: please show the dc.js code.

Comment: From the docs and your file, you need something like: chart.overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function(d) {
    return d.properties.ED;
});

Comment: It looks like you're asking the same question multiple ways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669922/why-dc-js-doesnt-draw-choropleth-map Please edit your existing questions instead of creating more.

Answer (score 4):

Without your code, hard to answer, but the problems I have usually with dc.js choropleth is

1) not using the right selector or key for overlayGeoJson(yourJson.features, "selector", function(d) { return d.name; });

- yourJson.features: geo json data (not topojson)
- "selector" - name of the layer which will be used to generate css class
- 3rd param - (optional) a function used to generate key for geo path, it should match the dimension key (eg. county name, iso of the country...

use jQuery/underscore/d3 to test your selector

2) not defining the projection (eg. mercator)

```
.projection(d3.geo.mercator())
```

3) having the wrong scale/transform
Here the map is properly drawn, but not in a visible scale

```
.scale(something)
.translate([x, y]))
```

But share your code (preferably on jfiddle), so we can have a look at it