# cant draw belgium on dc.js choropleth map

Tags: d3.js, geojson, dc.js, choropleth

I'm having trouble drawing belgium with a dc.js choropleth map.
I've read it can be a projection problem in another stackoverflow response ([map json works on Geojson.io but it doesnt work on dc.js choropleth map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671784/map-json-works-on-geojson-io-but-it-doesnt-work-on-dc-js-choropleth-map?answertab=votes#tab-top)), but I can't find the right parameters to write.

I would really appreciate any help with this issue.
Big thanks in advance !

---

Here is the geojson data I used:
https://github.com/Datafable/rolling-blackout-belgium/blob/master/data/geospatial/municipalities-belgium.geojson

And here is my code:

```
d3.json("data/municipalities-belgium.geojson", function (geojson) {
        mapChart
            .dimension(provinceDimension)
            .group(provinceGroup)
            .width(400)
            .height(400)
            .transitionDuration(1000)
            .projection(d3.geo.mercator()
                // .parallels([49, 52])
                // .origin([0,40])
                // .translate([200,900])
                // .scale(150000000)
            )
            .overlayGeoJson(geojson.features, 'somename', function(d) {
                return d.properties.shn;
            })
            ;
            dc.renderAll();
        });
```

(The result is a blue square 400x400 that seems to select shn=BE391141)

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you put a scale, you don't get anything drawn?

As for the overlay, the name of the dimension has to be the name of the province you want to set the color of. How is provinceDimension defined? does it use shn as the key?

As an aside, your geojson contains lots of stuff you don't need (eg uk), having it only for the belgium provinces would make it much smaller.

Comment: I tried all scales possible. shn is one key i beleive. And the geojson does not contain UK, what you see is the map github draws behind the geojson.